# Blazorise DataGrid syntax to create and execute Commands with parameters on a Button?

Tags: datagrid, blazor, blazorise

How does one save data (multiple rows) in a Blazorise DataGrid?

Is there an example of the code including the C# functions to update a database?

Comment: In addition to a Command example with command args, I would like to know how to edit a row inline with built-in edit/delete buttons (delete does hide the row, but save just hangs, does nothing).

Comment: <DataGrid TItem="WarehouseTransferDetailVM"
              ShowPager="true"
              PageSize="45"
              Filterable="false"
              Editable="true"
              Data="@Items"> ...        <DataGridColumn TItem="WarehouseTransferDetailVM" Field="@nameof(WarehouseTransferDetailVM.BoxUnitWeight)" Caption="Unit Wt" Filterable="false" Editable="false" Sortable="false" Width="80px" />
        <DataGridCommandColumn TItem="WarehouseTransferDetailVM">
        </DataGridCommandColumn>

Comment: I have a similar question where I just want to have an edit button in a column that will direct to a page to do the editing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66784414/datagrid-editing-on-separate-page-component

Answer (score 1):

Blazorise uses automatic CRUD - but you need to call something like this in code:

```
async Task OnSaveClicked()
{

    // check validation if needed

    if (Items != null)
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

to update the database.  It only needs to be done once for the whole grid.

I suggest using `EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Inline` for inline editing.

If an error occurs it will show a Reload at the bottom - check your browser developer tools to see what has caused the error.